# Incorrect command line parameter

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I am trying to install Yahoo messenger 10 from download. I am getting an error. It says in a windows installer window.  followed by

```
"Windows installer V2.00.2600.0
Copyright 2000 Microsoft

Portions of this software are based
in part on the work of Independent
JPEG Group"
```

I am using Windows XP  in Home. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something is passing a bad command-line to MSIEXEC.EXE. It also sounds like you're on an old version of Windows Installer. Updating Windows Installer may solve your problem, but you can always use something like Process Explorer to examine the command-line being passed to MSIEXEC to see what the problem is.